# Qt Организация взаимодействия иерархической модели и БД

Tags: sql, qt, sqlite, mvc

Есть данные, хранящиеся в БД (сейчас `SQLite`). Прошу помочь правильно, в соответствии с канонами, `MVC`, организовать работу с ними в `Qt`-приложении.
Данные в задаче имеют иерархическую структуру.

Например, поезда метро: есть несколько поездов, в каждом несколько вагонов, в каждом из них - несколько пассажиров.

Данные каждого уровня хранятся в своей таблице в БД и ссылаются вторичными ключами на записи в вышестоящих таблицах.
Например, таблицы `poezda`, `vagony` и `lyudi`. Каждая запись из таблицы `lyudi` связана с одной из записей в таблице `vagony`, а та, в свою очередь, ссылается на запись в таблице `poezda`. Всё стандартно, без изысков.

Сейчас сделана модель данных (унаследована от `QAbstractItemModel`), через которую реализована работа с БД.
Модель создана на основе примеров для данных древовидной структуры. Примеры брались из разных источников.
Модель хранит данные в памяти в виде связанного набора стандартных узлов (тип данных поезд/вагон/человек записан в поле `Type` узла, а сами данные, собранные в структуру, хранятся в `QVariant` поле `Data`).
При старте модель считывает все данные из БД и формирует полное дерево узлов (база данных небольшая).
Чтение, правка, удаление и добавление элементов происходят через методы `data`, `setData`, `removeRows` и `insertRows,` предусмотренные `QAbstractItemModel`.
При этом сначала определяется тип узла, потом производятся действия с `SQL` таблицей, соответствующей этому типу и уже потом, при необходимости, перестраивается дерево узлов в памяти.
Тип узла определяется по типу Родительского узла (индекс Родительского узла передаётся при вызове методов, а его тип считывается вызовом `data` со специальной ролью).

Если Родительский узел типа вагон, значит элемент, над которым производится действие - пассажир, а значит надо работать с `SQL`-таблицей `lyudi`. 
Такая организация, по всей видимости, принципиально неправильная. Сейчас она работает, но, во-первых, всё очень неудобно, во-вторых, изменения в БД в обход модели приводят к рассогласованию (обычная проблема), а в-третьих, небольшие изменения в предметной области приводят к неразрешимым проблемам.

Допустим, что на одном уровне могут находиться элементы разного типа, из разных `SQL`-таблиц. Например, пассажирами метро могут быть не только люди, но и собаки (таблица `zhivotnye`), кошки и марсиане (таблица `inoplanetyane`), блохи, депутаты (чисто теоретически) и глисты (таблица `parazity`). В этом случае, даже зная тип Родительского элемента, непонятно как определить нужную `SQL`-таблицу.

Пожалуйста, наведите на мысль, как правильно организовать модель и работу с БД в данном случае. Заранее всем благодарен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Допустим, что на одном уровне могут находиться элементы разного типа,
>   из разных SQL-таблиц. Например, пассажирами метро могут быть не только
>   люди, но и собаки (таблица zhivotnye), кошки и марсиане (таблица
>   inoplanetyane), блохи, депутаты (чисто теоретически) и глисты (таблица
>   parazity). В этом случае, даже зная тип Родительского элемента,
>   непонятно как определить нужную SQL-таблицу.

Насколько я понял у вас пассажиры связаны с вагонами. Для того, чтобы учесть возможность наличия пассажиров различных типов (кошек, людей, марсиан) можно использовать промежуточную таблицу связей vagon_passager_relation, состоящую из трех полей:

```
id_1 - id вагона;
id_2 - id пассажира из какой-либо таблицы;
reference_table_name - название таблицы в которой искать id_2.
```

Целостность данных в этом случае нужно обеспечивать через триггеры. Например, при удалении строки из таблицы люди, в триггере AFTER DELETE проверять наличие ссылки на данную строку в таблице vagon_passager_relation и удалять.

Comment: Вопрос больше связан с вызовом insertRows - ей передаются только позиция и число добавляемых записей и индекс Родительского узла (вагона). А чтобы запомнить изменения в базе, всё равно потребуется знать тип добавляемого узла.

Comment: @jasha, вы имеете в виду добавление нового пассажира пользователем? ну добавляете вы через insertRow пустую строку, а через setData заполняете, одновременно записываете в БД. или в чем проблема ?

Comment: То есть, insertRows не затрагивает БД, а меняет только внутреннюю структуру? Но тогда в случае провала добавления в БД из setData нужно будет откатывать то, что сделал insertRows... Ну можно, наверное... Всё равно остаётся ощущение, что это не самый правильный путь

Comment: @jasha, а что мешает сначала обновлять БД, а затем, в случае успеха обновлять модель?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду менять БД в обход модели? Или менять её только из setData, в том числе и добавлять записи, а insertRows вообще не использовать либо же использовать только для установки некого флага "следующий setData будет инсертным"? Или я вообще всё не так понял?

Comment: @jasha,ну вы можете сделать в модели дополнительную функцию insertPassager, которая сначала делает в ставку в бд, затем, в случае успеха, insertRow и setData.

Comment: Вот к этому варианту я и склонялся, но меня пугало, что это выходит за рамки интерфейса QAbstractItemModel. я плохо знаю идеологию MVC и опасался, что необходимость добавления нового метода в модель говорит о нарушении принципов MVC и об изначально неверной организации приложения

Comment: нет, не нарушает. вот пример использования моделей/представлений от разработчиков qt. В нем они добавляют в модель новые методы. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-puzzle-example.html

Comment: Ну тогда это, наверное, действительно лучший вариант. Благодарю Вас!

Comment: @jasha, если ответ вам помог - отметьте его как правильный